# Custom search in Dynamics CRM 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have a two related questions.

First:
I'm looking to do a full text search against a custom entity in Dynamics CRM 4.0. Has anyone done this before or know how to do it?

I know that I can build QueryExpressions with the web service and sdk but can I do a full text search with boolean type syntax using this method? As far as I can tell that won't do the trick.

Second:
Does anyone else feel limited with the searching abilities provided with Dynamics CRM 4.0? I know there are some 3rd pary search products out there but I haven't found one I like yet. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching and filtering via the CRM SDK does take some time to get used to.  In order to simulate full text search, you need to use nested FilterExpressions as your QueryExpression.Criteria.  [SDK page for nested filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928435.aspx)  The hardest part is figuring out how to build the parent child relationships.  There's so much boolean logic going on that it's easy to get lost.

I had a requirement to build a "search engine" for one of our custom entities.  Using this method for a complex search string ("one AND two OR three") with multiple searchable attributes was ugly.  If you're interested though, I can dig it up.  While it's not really supported, if you can access the database directly, I would suggest using SQL's full text search capabilities.

--
ok, here you go.  I don't think you'll be able to copy paste this and fulfill your needs.  my customer was only doing two to three key word searches and they were happy with the results from this.  You can see what a pain it is to just do this in a simple search scenario.  I basically puked out code until it was 'working'.

```
    private FilterExpression BuildFilterV2(string[] words, string[] seachAttributes)
    {
        FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression();
        List<FilterExpression> allchildfilters = new List<FilterExpression>();

        List<string> andbucket = new List<string>();
        List<string> orBucket = new List<string>();

        // clean up commas, quotes, etc
        words = ScrubWords(words);

        int index = 0;

        while (index < words.Length)
        {
            // if current word is 'and' then add the next wrod to the ad bucket
            if (words[index].ToLower() == "and")
            {
                andbucket.Add(words[index + 1]);
                index += 2;
            }
            else
            {
                if (andbucket.Count > 0)
                {

                    List<FilterExpression> filters = new List<FilterExpression>();
                    foreach (string s in andbucket)
                    {
                        filters.Add(BuildSingleWordFilter(s, seachAttributes));
                    }

                    // send existing and bucket to condition builder 
                    FilterExpression childFilter = new FilterExpression();
                    childFilter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;
                    childFilter.Filters = filters.ToArray();

                    // add to child filter list
                    allchildfilters.Add(childFilter);

                    //new 'and' bucket
                    andbucket = new List<string>();
                }
                if (index + 1 < words.Length && words[index + 1].ToLower() == "and")
                {
                    andbucket.Add(words[index]);
                    if (index + 2 <= words.Length)
                    {
                        andbucket.Add(words[index + 2]);
                    }
                    index += 3;
                }
                else
                {
                    orBucket.Add(words[index]);
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (andbucket.Count > 0)
        {
            List<FilterExpression> filters = new List<FilterExpression>();
            foreach (string s in andbucket)
            {
                filters.Add(BuildSingleWordFilter(s, seachAttributes));
            }

            // send existing and bucket to condition builder 
            FilterExpression childFilter = new FilterExpression();
            childFilter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;
            childFilter.Filters = filters.ToArray();

            // add to child filter list
            allchildfilters.Add(childFilter);

            //new 'and' bucket
            andbucket = new List<string>();
        }
        if (orBucket.Count > 0)
        {
            filter.Conditions = BuildConditions(orBucket.ToArray(), seachAttributes);
        }
        filter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.Or;
        filter.Filters = allchildfilters.ToArray();

        return filter;
    }
    private FilterExpression BuildSingleWordFilter(string word, string[] seachAttributes)
    {
        List<ConditionExpression> conditions = new List<ConditionExpression>();

        foreach (string attr in seachAttributes)
        {
                ConditionExpression expr = new ConditionExpression();
                expr.AttributeName = attr;
                expr.Operator = ConditionOperator.Like;
                expr.Values = new string[] { "%" + word + "%" };

                conditions.Add(expr);
        }

        FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression();
        filter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.Or;
        filter.Conditions = conditions.ToArray();

        return filter;
    }

    private ConditionExpression[] BuildConditions(string[] words, string[] seachAttributes)
    {
        List<ConditionExpression> conditions = new List<ConditionExpression>();

        foreach (string s in words)
        {
            foreach (string attr in seachAttributes)
            {
                ConditionExpression expr = new ConditionExpression();
                expr.AttributeName = attr;
                expr.Operator = ConditionOperator.Like;
                expr.Values = new string[] { "%" + s + "%" };

                conditions.Add(expr);
            }
        }

        return conditions.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mikeyb,

Thanks for the answer. It would be a help if you could dig it up. I was thinking about using SQL Server full text searching and probably will end up going that way unless I can find a good way to do it through the APIs available to me.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, that's a pretty interesting scenario...

You could certainly do a 'Like' query, and 'or' together the colums/attribute conditions you want included in the search. This seems to be how CRM does queries from the box above entity lists (and they're plenty fast). It looks like the CRM database has a full-text index, although exactly which columns are used to populate it is a bit foggy to me after a brief peek.

And remember [LinqtoCRM](http://www.codeplex.com/LINQtoCRM/) for CRM query love (I started the project, sorry about the shameless plug).

Answer (score 1):

Second - I can recommend "Global Search" by Akvelon which provides ability to search in all Custom Entities and attributes and Out of Box entities and attributes. Also they are using FTS for search in the attached documents contents. You can find more details in their official site: http://www.akvelon.com/Products/Dynamics%20CRM%20global%20Search/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest utilizing the Dynamics CRM filtered views provided for you in the database. Then you can utilize all the power of native SQL to do any LIKE's or other logic you need. Plus, the filtered views are security trimmed, so you won't have to worry about users accessing records they do not have permission to.